# My python turtle is on the correct coordinates for my if statement to return as true, yet my if statement is not returning as true

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

What I made is when the turtle is on the coordinates `(0,-285)`, and i press the spacebar it should print `'yay'`, and the coordinates, otherwise it should print `'no'` and the coordinates. But every time I press spacebar, it prints 'no', even when I'm on the correct coordinates. May I have some help with this?

```
import turtle
import time
import random
t = turtle.Pen()
t.speed(0)
check = (0,0)

x = turtle.window_width()
y = turtle.window_height()
#defining functions to move
def turn_left():
    t.left(90)
def turn_right():
    t.right(90)
def forward():
    t.forward(15)
def backward():
    t.backward(15)
def check_pos():
    check = t.pos()
    print(check)
    if check == (0,-285):
        print('yay')
    else:
        print('no')
turtle.onkeypress(turn_left, "Left")
turtle.onkeypress(turn_right, "Right")
turtle.onkeypress(forward, "Up")
turtle.onkeypress(backward, "Down")
turtle.onkeypress(check_pos, "space")
turtle.listen()
```

[Python Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFGFh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set boundaries like so:

```
def check_pos():
    check = t.pos()
    print(check)
    if t.distance(0,-285) < 10:
        print('yay')
    else:
        print('no')
```